# Android Layout Issue - ListView Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list view and each item is rendered as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip">

   <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/projectImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/project_icon" 
        android:contentDescription = "@string/projectIcon" />       

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/projectDetails"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dip">    

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"        
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />   

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"                
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"                
            android:textSize="14sp"         
            android:singleLine="true"           
            android:textColor="@color/locationText_color"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" />
   </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

But my listview is not rendered properly the list item is too short and it doesnt show any content See below

[image]

I do use custom styles. I also tried changing

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

To

```
android:layout_height="100dip"
```

but it didnt work.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter? If yes how are you inflating the layout file in the `getView` method? Like this: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)`?

Comment: no i was using... `inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_fragment_list, null)` changed it to what you mentioned and it works :) but it doesnt show the two text views just shows image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as I said in my comment, you should always use this version of the `inflate()` method when you inflate the row layout file so you setup the right `LayoutParams` for the row view:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)
```

Regarding the two `TextViews` not appearing, I'm not sure how exactly do you want them to be placed. Here is what I think:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip">

   <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/projectImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/project_icon" 
        android:contentDescription = "@string/projectIcon" />       

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/projectDetails"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"        
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />   

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"                
            android:textSize="14sp"         
            android:singleLine="true"           
            android:textColor="@color/locationText_color"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" />
   </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height of your TextViews to 0dp.

```
    android:layout_height="0dip"
```

Change it to `wrap_content` or set weights to your TextViews. The weight of the parent LinearLayout does not apply to them.

Comment: i tried it.. didnt work. I already have weight assigned to inner LinearLayout. That should be enough?